# What is the difference between using `text-align:center` and `margin: 0 auto` to center an element in CSS?

Tags: css

I have read in a lot of places to center elements (a div for example) using `margin:0 auto`.
but why not use `align:center`?
I think it seems more natural to use the later.

Also, can we use `margin` approach to set vertical alignment too?

Comment: Capitalization is important. :) People will tend to take your questions more seriously if you take the time to write them properly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, there is no "align: center".  What you're thinking of is "text-align: center", and that detail — the prefix "text-" — is a hint as to what the problem is. The "text-align" property is for inline elements being laid out in blocks.  When you're trying to center a block-level element in some content, an inline layout style does not make sense.

The (now **deprecated**) align attribute on elements is not a CSS thing; it's a throwback to the days of yesteryear.

Now, as to *vertical* alignment, sadly the answer is "no," at least in practical terms.  The trick with "margin: auto" won't work. Vertical alignment with nothing but CSS is challenging, to put it mildly. There are many different situations and techniques to use. Here's an interesting (if a little old) page on the subject: http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/

*edit from the future* — Anybody trying to do vertical centering should be keeping an eye on the availability of [flexbox layout](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: In 2015 flexbox layout is yet to gain following (though most browsers do appear to be supporting it to some extent), but vertical-align can be achieved using css tables. Basically the same thing as with the now shunned table layout, except instead of table, tr and td, you have div's with display set to table and table-cell (in fact you need only those two elements). I suspect flexbox will gain more following when HTML apps gain popularity and more people have flexbox compatible browsers on their mobile devices (phones, tablets etc.). Flexbox layout can make a lot of difference there.

Comment: "Vertical alignment with nothing but CSS is challenging" definitely not the case and you have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: fair point. There are definitely tons of ways to do it now but even back then it wasn't challenging...

Answer (score 28):

`text-align: center` will center the contents of the container, while `margin: auto` will center the container itself.

You should be careful with `margin:auto` because it is not supported in IE6. In IE6, you should set `text-align:center` on the outer container, and reset the CSS for the container itself to `text-align:left`.

Comment: That is not true: "margin: auto" is supported by IE6 when you've got a DOCTYPE that puts it in standards-compliant mode (as opposed to "quirks" mode).

Comment: It could be better if you present an example.

Answer (score 7):

`text-align=center` used to align the **content** (text for example) to center, however `margin: auto` is used to align the element itself to center.

In older browsers however (IE), you could align **elements** to center using `text-align:center`.

But I suspect you meant `align=center` like in below example:

```
<p align="center">
 .......
</p>

<h1 align="center">
 .......
</h1>
```

However, not all elements have `align="center"`, you will have to use `margin:0 auto` to align for them.

**So,**

If you want to align **content** of an element, you should do:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
 .......
</p>
```

If you want to align element itself, you should do:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
 .......
</div>

<p style="margin:0 auto;">
 .......
</p>
```