# When do I Use Center and Auto Margin? CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, center

I am learning CSS in Codecademy. I had already taken their HTML course so I knew about the `center` tag. However, now they introduced the CSS margin property. They also introduced the `margin: 0 auto;` property. From my knowledge, both do exactly the same thing. So is there any differences and when do I use each one or does it not matter? Thank You In Advance!

Comment: This question is already solved [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392563/what-is-the-difference-between-using-text-aligncenter-and-margin-0-auto-to) is the link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using \`text-align:center\` and \`margin: 0 auto\` to center an element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392563/what-is-the-difference-between-using-text-aligncenter-and-margin-0-auto-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<center>` is an depreciated tag. You should avoid using it. This tag is not supported in HTML5. CSS property is used to set the align of the element instead of the `center` tag in HTML5. An equivalent tag to `<center>` can be considered to be -

```
.center { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
```

The main reason why `<center>` was depreciated was because it defines the presentation of its contents and not the contents itself. According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) -

> The CENTER element is exactly equivalent to specifying the DIV element
> with the align attribute set to "center". The CENTER element is
> deprecated.

---

> So is there any differences and when do I use each one or does it not matter?

The above code snippet and `<center>` can be considered equivalent. Just using `margin: 0 auto;` can't always be considered the same though. See the below example -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <center>
    <div>This is a div inside center</div>
  </center>
  <br>

  <div>This is a div without any styling.</div>
  <br>

  <div style="margin: 0 auto;">This is a div with "margin: auto 0px;".Text not centered, doesn't work.</div>
  <br>

  <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center">This is a div with "margin: auto 0px;".Text centered, works !</div>


</body>

</html>
```

---

Another point to consider is that The `<center>` tag is a **block-level element**, which means it can contain other block-level and inline elements and center them. Consider below example -

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <!--p has a width of 200px given through css-->
  <center>
    <p>centers the element to page center</p>
  </center>
  <center>


  <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
    <p>This one doesn't work here same as center tag </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">This one does</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just for the record, `margin: 0 auto` IS NOT the same as `margin: auto 0`

Comment: @IvanS95 Yea, wrote it by mistake. Was meaning to mention `margin: 0 auto`. Edited it now to avoid confusion

Comment: @Alohci you can probably and an answer to this ;) I am not able to find an answer explaning how the center tag affect the layout (considering block and inline elements)

Comment: you gave an equivalence and your last example is showing that your equivalence is wrong.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that's what I mentioned. It's not exactly the same in each case. I gave an example where they differ.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I'm not sure this is the right location for an answer to "What exactly is the CSS equivalent of the `<center>` element". The element and `margin:auto` are too different. Incidentally, I misread the HTML 4.01 quote. It is correct, it just isn't implemented by `text-align:center`, or `margin:auto` or by a combination of them.

Comment: @Alohci But in most use-cases, though not same in every sense, `<center>` can be replace using those css properties, right?

Comment: @Abhishek - Right. As you indicate, it's basically just a case of putting those properties on the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 2):

As the W3Schools wiki describes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp), the `<center></center>` tag is not supported by HTML5, although browsers will still work with it because of backwards-compatibility. Your best bet is to use the `margin: 0 auto` property.